# Why my htaccess rule is not working unless it's directed to a PHP file

Tags: .htaccess, apache

My htaccess file is under "myappname" folder.

I'm trying to redirect this path;

```
myappname/CONTROLLER_NAME/ANYFILE.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)
```

To that path

```
myappname/views/default/tpl/CONTROLLER_NAME/ANYFILE.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)
```

and this is my HTACCESS rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)$ views/default/tpl/$1/$2.$3 [L,NC]
```

but it's giving me HTTP 500 unless I redirect it to a PHP file like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)$ views/default/tpl/$1/index.php?a=$2.$3 [L,NC]
```

What is wrong with my rule? I'm very new to htaccess and there is a very big potential to I'm missing something small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your target matches the regex:

```
views/default/tpl/foo/bar.png
```

matches the regex:

```
^(.*)/(.*)\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)$
```

So the rules just keep looping. You need to add a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/default/tpl
```

right above your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: A bit late and one of my colleagues explained that behaviour to me and we've fixed the problem but I accepted your answer anyway since it's a legitimate answer. Thanks for your help.